# django templates: get many-to-many value in formset

Tags: python, django, templates, many-to-many, formset

models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   ...
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   ...

class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
   ...
```

forms:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

booklist.html :

```
<table>
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ form.title.value }} </td>
    <td> {{ form.authors }} </td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

So, this outputs a multiple select box for each book's authors.
How do I get the first_name of the authors in the template?

Thanks,
Adi

edit: added views

views:

```
def thebooks(request):
  BookFormSet = modelformset_factory(Book, form = BookForm)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = BookFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
      formset.save()
  else:
    formset = BookFormSet(queryset = Book.objects.all())
  return render_to_response('thebooks.html', {'formset': formset,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )

def booklist(request):
  BookFormSet = modelformset_factory(Book, form = BookForm)
  formset = BookFormSet(request.POST)
  return render_to_response('booklist.html', {'formset':formset,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

js code to load the booklist page in the thebooks page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form").submit(function() {
        $.post('/books/booklist/', $(this).serialize(),
          function(data) {
            if (data == "") { alert("No data returned!"); return; }
            // otherwise set the content div to the data we received
            $('#allElements').html(data);
          }
        );
        // disable normal submitting of the form since we use ajax now
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the model instance in an edit form as such:

```
<td>
    {% if form.instance.pk %}{# if this is the form of an existing book #}
        {% for author in form.instance.authors.all %}
            {# then you can iterate over the authors of the book #}
            {{ author.first_name }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</td>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work...no error...nothing...just doesn't display the name

Comment: Interesting, post the view and form python code so that we can give it a try.

Comment: I added the views code. 
Actually "booklist" is displayed in a div inside the "thebooks" page. using the js code. So the author name thing (the template code) is in the booklist view

Comment: Ok i didn't understand your question, i thought you wanted the list of **available** authors for the field. I updated the answer with a working example of how to access the authors which are related to the book.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **unicode** method on the model class for Authors:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   ...
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   ...
   def __unicode__(self):
       return first_name
```

In the dropdown just use {{ form.authors }}. Instead of it saying Author: Model Object (or whatever it normally says) it will now say "John" if the persons first name is John.

The advantage here of course is that you also have direct access to the id once selected as well.

Comment: i have the unicode function already defined...it only formats the way how the authors are displayed in the multiple select box generated by the formset.
my question was how can i access manytomany field real values from the template.